# Proper use of memset with dynamically allocated multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, memset

At each iteration of a loop I wish to zero all elements in a dynamically defined multidimensional array.

```
void my_function(int window_size, int row_size){

        double **window_arr;
        window_arr = (double **)calloc((window_size * 2), sizeof(double*));
            for (i = 0; i < (window_size * 2); ++i){
                window_arr[i] = (double*)calloc(3, sizeof(double));
            }
        for (i = 0; i < row_size; ++i){
           ...
           memset(window_arr, 0, sizeof(window_arr) * (window_size * 2) * 3);
        }
    }
```

This seg faults.  Setting a break point before the first `memset`, but after allocation, looks good.

```
(gdb) p window_arr[1]
$1 = (double *) 0x22604f50
(gdb) p window_arr[1][0]
$2 = 0
(gdb) q
```

The break point after the `memset`

```
(gdb) p snp_window_arr[1]
$1 = (double *) 0x0
(gdb) p window_arr[1][0]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) q
```

I have figured out how to use memset for 1d arrays; I would really like to learn how to use memset in the above-described scenario.

Comment: Could you call memset immediately after the second calloc (inside the loop)?

Comment: Also, I can't really make sense of your use of memset. Shouldn't its third arg be something like: sizeof(double) * (window_size * 2) * 3

Comment: You're also assuming 2d arrays are contiguous, which I'm not sure is guaranteed (it may be). If not, my first suggestion is safest -- memset each row separately.

Comment: It is not portable to zero floating point variables by zeroing memory (with either `calloc` or `memset`). You should loop through the entries and set them individually to `0.0`. (But why would you use memset after using calloc? calloc already zeroes the memory it returns.)

Comment: @ooga, because each iteration of the loop uses the array for some calculation, which then needs to then be zeroed.

Comment: @RobJinman, thanks, I'll loop through and try to memset each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building an array of pointers to arrays, rather than a single 2D array.  That means you have an array of pointers, and each pointer points to a 1D array.  Then you try to `memset()` the entire 2D space, but this is impossible because it is not contiguously allocated.

You should consider allocating a single array with space for all your elements at once, since your logical 2D array is rectangular anyway.  Just do this:

```
double *window_arr = calloc((window_size * 2) * 3, sizeof(double));
```

Then:

```
memset(window_arr, 0, (window_size * 2) * 3);
```

Of course you will then index into this 2D array as `window_arr[x*window_size*2 + y]` or similar, rather than `window_arr[x][y]`.